# Nivo Background Position is Being Ignored

Tags: css, background-position, nivo-slider

Would like it someone could help me troubleshoot my css for the background positioning on a nivo slider I'm implementing on a new design.

The background-position is being ignored for `.nivo-nextNav` and I can't figure out why.

Here is my css:

```
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
display:block;
width:43px;
height:45px;
background:url(../images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
text-indent:-9999px;
border:0;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
background-position: -43px 0;
right: 22px;
}
```

Link to the page: http://www.plumeriawebdesign.com/Headstand%20Software/

I have it working now.  I changed the css for `.nivo-directionNav a` to the following:

```
.nivo-directionNav a {
position:absolute;
top:40%;
z-index:9;
cursor:pointer;
width: 43px;
height: 45px;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-image:url(../images/arrows.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Now the background is positioned properly. Curious though why it works on their default slider on their site and not mine. Strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your background position is set to the .nivo-nextNav, but .nivo-nextNav doesn't have a background, the link does; the 'a' in .nivo-nextNav a <-

easiest solution: Put the position in the background;

```
 .nivo-directionNav a {
 .......
 background:url(../images/arrows.png) -43px 0 no-repeat;
```

Comment: It does have the background. It is inherited from `.nivo-directionNav a` Setting the position for this class isn't going to solve the issue because it needs to change for both `.nivo-prevNav` and `.nivo-nextNav`.

Answer (score 0):

background-position only positions the background-image. But there is no background-image in your .nivo-nextNav element.

From what I see NivoSlider uses the arrows like this:

```
.nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(arrow.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}
a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position:-30px 0;
    right:15px;
}
a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:15px;
}
```

Try using the anchor tag in the beggining of your elements.